# Android FragmentManager for same Activity hide() doesnt work

Tags: android, hide, show, fragmentmanager

Hi guys im working on my MainActivity and I am dealing with the following problem:

In my MainActivity I have 3 buttons(button1, button2, button3). With each I can add a `Fragment(Fragment2, Fragment1, ProfileFragment)` to my container. Everytime a button is pressed, it checks the Fragments if there is already anotherone visible.

If yes, `FragmentManager().beginnTransaction().fragment.hide()` should hide it.

Then it checks if the fragment bound to the button already exists.

If no, it adds it.

If yes, it should make the existing hidden fragment visible again with `FragmentManager().beginnTransaction().fragment.show()`

Now: If I press `button2` as the first when I start my App everything works fine and I can infinitely switch between the fragments.

**But: If I press `button1` as the first, and then switch to `button2` or `button3`, the fragment bound to `button1` (`m2fragment`) can't be shown again.** It just shows `m1fragment` (which should be hidden when I press `button1`)

The same happens if I press button3 as the first. Everytime I try to switch back to `button3`(`profileFragment`) it just shows m1fragment.

May be there a problem with the googleMap which I call from the xml from `m2Fragment`??

Anyone can see where I made (a) mistake(s) ? I would be really glad since I am dealing with this for several days now.

Thank you all !

Cut from my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        OfferFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, MapsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, OpenerFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    protected int fragment1Open = 0;
    protected int fragment2Open = 0;
    protected int profileFragmentOpen = 0;
    Fragment1 m1Fragment = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 m2Fragment = new Fragment2();
    ProfileFragment mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    OpenerFragment mOpenerFragment = new OpenerFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,mOpenerFragment).commit();
        }

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //check fragments
                if(mOpenerFragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mOpenerFragment).commit();
                    Log.d("button1", "remove OpenerFragment");
                }
                if(m1Fragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(m1Fragment).commit();
                }
                if(mProfileFragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mProfileFragment).commit();
                }

                if(fragment2Open==0) {
                    fragment2Open=1;
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, m2Fragment).commit();
                } else {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(m2Fragment).commit();
                }

            }
        });

        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //hide other fragments
                if(mOpenerFragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mOpenerFragment).commit();
                }
                if(mProfileFragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mProfileFragment).commit();
                }
                if(m2Fragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(m2Fragment).commit();
                }

                if(fragment1Open==0) {
                    fragment1Open=1;
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, m1Fragment).commit();
                } else {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(m1Fragment).commit();
                }

            }
        });

        final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //hide other fragments
                if(mOpenerFragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mOpenerFragment).commit();
                }
                if(m1Fragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(m1Fragment).commit();
                }
                if(m2Fragment.isVisible()) {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(m2Fragment).commit();
                }

                //open fragment
                if(profileFragmentOpen==0) {
                    profileFragmentOpen=1;
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mProfileFragment).commit();
                } else {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mProfileFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

mProfileFragment and m2Fragment use identically onCreate and onCreateView methods:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
```

m1Fragment has the same methods, but gets a googleMaps fragment from its xml file.

m1Fragment:

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            MapFragment mapFragment=(MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(mapid);
            if (mapFragment==null) {
                mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, mapFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            //right upper corner, location layer activated
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
```

fragment_1.xml:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@id/mapid"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it:

Withing my `MapsFragment` class I instantiated a googleMaps fragment "twice". Trying to hide the `mapFragment` I just hid one of them, leaving the other one visible in front.

For people having similar issues here my solution:
I erased the

```
<fragment
        android:id="@id/mapid"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

from the xml layout file.

And inside the `MapsFragment` class I changed

```
MapFragment mapFragment=(MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(mapid);
```

to

```
MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framLay, mapFragment).commit();
```

Now I put one clean Instance of MapFragment into my FrameLayout and it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
MapFragment mapFragment=(MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(mapid);
```

in this line your actually tring to get the parent's fragmentManager (in your case the activity),and fail to find the fragment.
and then in this line:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, mapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

you are adding to the parent FragmentManager.

a quick to solution is to replace getFragmentManger() with getChildFragmentManager, which refers to the fragment's FragmentManager.

Comment: Thanks Yossi! I understand what I did wrong here now and it led me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use :

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

With `fragment_container` as FrameLayout in your activity?

I'm not 100% sure, but i think it'll avoid such issues

Comment: Thanks Nik! On my first try it didn't solve my problem, but it improved my code bcs now it implements the backstack aswell.